# NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken returning nil

Tags: xcode, icloud, nsfilemanager

I have an OS X app all correctly setup for using iCloud. If I archive the app and save it as an app in the applications folder and run it, it works with iCloud, but if I run it from Xcode, NSFileManager's ubiquityIdentityToken will always return nil. Anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by enabling all apps in iCloud preferences->documents and data. I don't know why this helps as the app I am developing has always been iCloud enabled, but it is working now.